# Parsing a value as a field when mapping through an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In the mongoDB aggregation framework I am trying to parse a value as a field when mapping through an array - but no luck so far, i.e. [mongoplayground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AV8HlDoGz6n). Any pointers welcome because the only other alternative I can think of is to query the db twice which seems like a waste. Expected result in the link:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "myField2_e": "field_a1",
    "routesArr_e": [
      {
        "field_a1": 8197,
        "field_a2": "a string",
        "field_b": "b string",
        "field_c": 8197
      },
      {
        "field_a1": 8198,
        "field_a2": "aa string",
        "field_b": "bb string",
        "field_c": 8198
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: @turivishal Please check the link which shows perfectly what I am trying to achieve in `field_c`. With thanks_

Comment: if i understand you need to assign `myField_e` in `field_c`, so try this `"field_c": "$myField_e"`.

Comment: @turivishal I am trying to get `routesArr_e.eField_a.field_a1` in this example. But the field `myField_e` determines the field to retrieve the value from

Comment: @turivishal So if `myField_e` was `field_a2` then I would want to return `routesArr_e.eField_a.field_a2`

Comment: @turivishal As I say the value should change if `myField_e` is different. So if `myField_e` was `field_a2` then I would want to return that field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$reduce` and `$objectToArray` to convert object in array and check condition using `$cond` if field is match with `myField_e` then return otherwise blank,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      myField2_e: "$myField_e",
      routesArr_e: {
        $map: {
          input: "$mainField_e.routesArr_e",
          in: {
            "field_a1": "$$this.eField_a.field_a1",
            "field_a2": "$$this.eField_a.field_a2",
            "field_b": "$$this.field_b",
            "field_c": {
              $reduce: {
                input: { $objectToArray: "$$this.eField_a" },
                initialValue: "",
                in: {
                  $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this.k", "$myField_e"] }, "$$this.v", "$$value"]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KcIIUeQWqCU)